# Why do elements nudge down upon rotation, in grid container

Tags: html, css

I stumbled across an oddity in CSS. Briefly told, when rotating a div upon hover, the contents within the div nudges down what looks like 1 pixel or so. It only happens at certain view heights.

Here is a gif that shows the issue (notice how the text "One" nudges about one pixel):

[image]

Here is the smallest reproduction I was able to make:

```css
.header {
  background-color: orange;
    height: 30vh;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.front {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.back {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back,
.front {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 1s;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> HEADER </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="front">
    <h2>One</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="back">Two</div>
</div>
```

A Codepen with the same code, in case the above is hard to resize: [Codepen showing issue](https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/WNKXrrv?editors=1100)

The problem does not occur on all screen heights, so activate DevTools then shrink the height of the screen gradually, trying a hover at each height. It will nudge upon rotation at certain heights. The nudge causes any card flip animation to look bad.

Comment: It's probably not moving anywhere (if it is, you can `console.log` the result of `getBoundingClientRect()` on that element to verify). I think you'll find that it is an optical illusion because of the colors though; try putting a blue square right next to a red square and see if the outer edge looks jagged; the red filter for the LCD is offset from the blue filter. If you use similar colors (or animate the colors so that the change is more gradual), it won't look as bad. If I'm not mistaken; I certainly could be (hence the comment, not answer).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think it's an optical illusion - eg. if you scale up the gif so it's easier to see what's going on there's a definite jump up of the content at the end of the rotation. I suspect (but again don't know) that it's caused by edge-effects when the system is having to calculate screen pixels versus CSS pixels - sort of like a rounding error. It won't happen always.

Comment: Can't repro but this looks like a switch on the renderer for when your element is transformed or not. You can try to set `transform: translateZ(0deg);` on your `.front` element in "stable" position. This should force the use of the same renderer all along.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks. Were you able to make that work? I added it to the codepen, but no difference? I might have added it the wrong place, I did not quite get what you meant with "stable" position.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Unfortunately, it is not an optical illusion. I have a grid of cards that flip upon hover, and they seemingly arbitrarily jump/nudge around upon hover. Breaks the UX flow.

Comment: I mean in your default `.front` rule, when it's not animated. And as I said, I couldn't reproduce the issue to begin with, so no, I couldn't test this workaround directly on it.

Comment: @Kaiido Hmmm, for some reason you have to make the dev tools container smaller, and try to hover on every shrinking of the container. It seems to have something to do with scroll or window size. I have a grid of card that seemingly arbitrarily nudge around upon hover, depending on height of window (some also on full height). I have not found a pattern. I tried adding the rule you gave, but no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, I could repro, but for me adding `transform: translateZ(0px)` to the `.front` rule does fix the issue.

Comment: @Kaiido Can you try this Codepen: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/WNKXrrv?editors=1100. It has your fix, but it shows the same issue. Try changing height of DevTools again perhaps?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in my first comment, fixed in my second though, it's `transform: translateZ(0px)`, `deg` is invalid here.

Comment: @Kaiido Amazing, that solved it in the Codepen. For some reason, it did not do the trick in my own code though. Could there be other fields interfering with it? I see that it has been applied (it is not slashed out in devtools). Also, if you mark it as *!important*, even in the Codepen, the front refuses to flip. Any idea why?

Comment: Regarding the `!important` preventing the flip that's because this rule will take precedence over the `:hover` one, which `transform: rotateY()` will thus get ignored. For what happens in your code, I don't know.

Comment: @Kaiido For some reason, the elegant solution you proposed stops working when adding `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to the inner divs. Codepen: codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/Expboqe. It seems justify-content is what breaks it. Any idea why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It indeed only happens on small browser height.

It works without jumping if you change `vh` to `px` in `.header`.

In you case, I would add @media query for screens with small height and vh for bigger screens.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 160px) {
    .header {
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to solve this with grid overlay (i.e. `grid-area: 1/1`)? I have generally moved over to doing overlays (overlapping) with *grid* and not with `absolute` positioning. Not sure if that is advised against, but seemed like a newer approach.

Comment: Ugh, I updated the Codepen with your solution, but the issue still appears with absolute positioning instead of grid. Check it out: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/WNKXrrv?editors=1100

Comment: You are right. Absolute positioning does not make any difference.
What worked for me is changing `vh` units to `px` in `.header`. Please, check updated solution.

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately that does not help me, as I need to use vh to get the header dynamic/responsive. But it is interesting to note that the unit on the header is partially the culprit.